# Problems with, manage of camera and Image view

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview

I'm developing an app using a camera intent to take a photo and an image view to show it. I've two problems, first is with the camera.

I have an activity only to manage the camera behaviour, the code of this manager is based on the sample of developer.google.com.
The issue is on the camera interface.
When I open the camera on vertical position, take a photo and accept de preview, all the process on vertical position, all works fine. The same behaviour with horizontal position.

But If accepts the photo preview in a different position how was started the camera interface, don't ends. It seems like the camera were restarted and I can take another photo. 
In addition, when this occurs the photo is not saved correctly, on gallery I don't see the picture, has a message 'Couldn't load photo'.

My other problem it's similar, but this time occurs on an ImageView. When I have the ImageView setted with an image, after rotate my device the image disappears.
This issue only occurs when I've taken a new photo, if the image is already in system all works fine.

EDIT:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
OnClick {
  Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  File f = null;
  try {
    f = createImageFile();
    mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
  }
  startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
OnActivityResult {
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
      galleryAddPic(); //Method to save the pic in the gallery
      finishActivity();
    } else {
      Log.e("ActivityResult", "Photo path is null");
    }
} else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
  finishActivity();
 }
}
```

EDIT 2: I just resolve the second issue, I'm beginner on developing apps and I don't knew that rotate the device restarts the interface and all modifications on the data after OnCreate should be saved on OnSaveInstanceState.

Now I only have one problem. I try it the strange behaviour in other device and it's the same.

Comment: Please provide a code sample to reproduce the issue. [SO guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you format the code. Looks like some lines are missing.

Comment: Sorry, now is formated